# Hibernate Performance - JProfiler shows unneeded & irrelevant operations that take a lot of time

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, database-performance, jprofiler

Big picture: **DB performance problem** in a Java server app with Hibernate, running in WebSphere connected to IBM DB2 DataBase.

Using JProfiler, I noticed that **in addition to the intended query, much more time is wasted on unneeded calls**.

Please see the attached image for a concrete example: [JProfiler screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGJg7.jpg)

- the useful queries executions are in the green area. These are all very simple queries, `select * from table where id = 123456` .
- the unneeded and not relevant operations are in the red area. These are **ALL completely irrelevant** to the query I run and the data that I retrieve, but have **one thing in common**: they are *getter* methods of various entity classes that had already been retrieved by hibernate prior to that moment.

Is this caused by some wrong/incomplete Hibernate cache configuration ?
I have these two lines in my config file (among others...)

```
<prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
    org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">
    false</prop>
```

Am I correct to assume that before running the query, Hibernate checks it's cache to see maybe some of the needed data is already there, and that it's those checks that take much more time than the *SELECT* itself ?

**Can I eliminate these not needed operations ?**

Thank you.

Comment: Can you tell us what the unneeded queries are doing?  I know you're trying to hid private information but you've hidden all of it.

Comment: @stdunbar

ALL those queries are exactly the queries which I intend to run, nothing not needed there. They are actually pretty simple, just some SELECT from ONE single table. `select * from _table_ where _id_ = 123456` .

ALL the unneeded operations are calls to getter methods belonging to DTO objects that (presumably) have previously been managed by the DAO layer of my app. And NONE of this is in any way related or connected to the particular selects that I'm running now.